# Angular 9 - resultSelector is no longer supported

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm getting `resultSelector is no longer supported` when using zip, but I'm not sure how to refactor it according to ngrx 7

```
 this.update.pipe(debounceTime(600),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(data => {
    const { gri, index } = data;
    const reqGri = Object.assign({}, gri);
    delete reqGri.id;
    return zip(
      this.dataManager.putGris(gri.id, reqGri),
      of(index), resGri => {
        return { resGri: resGri[0], index: resGri[1] };
      });
  })).subscribe((data) => {
    this.data[data.index] = data.resGri;
    this.dataChange.next([...this.data]);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refactoring should be identical, but now you're using zip without a `resultSelector`. All you do is format `zip`'s result via a `map`

```
this.update.pipe(debounceTime(600),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(data => {
    const { gri, index } = data;
    const reqGri = Object.assign({}, gri);
    delete reqGri.id;
    return zip(
      this.dataManager.putGris(gri.id, reqGri),
      of(index)
    ).pipe(
      map(resGri => ({ resGri: resGri[0], index: resGri[1]}))
    );
  })
).subscribe(data => {
  this.data[data.index] = data.resGri;
  this.dataChange.next([...this.data]);
});
```

or with destructuring to make it a bit cleaner

```
map(resGri => ({ resGri: resGri[0], index: resGri[1]}))
// can be changed to
map(([resGri, index]) => ({ resGri, index}))
```